# Prevent element from being dragged on touch devices

Tags: jquery, css

I have had a go at coding my own push menu using css and jquery.

The issue is that on touch devices you can 'drag' .wrapper left and it overlaps the nav element when it is open - it looks terrible!

How would i prevent this from happening? I don't want the .wrapper to be position:fixed.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/cL0ej1v3/1/

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#menuToggle").click(function() {
$('.wrapper, header, nav').toggleClass('push');
});

$("nav a").click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
        $(".wrapper,header,nav").removeClass('push');
},1000);
});

$(".wrap").click(function(){
$(".wrapper,header,nav").removeClass('push');
});
```

Here is the css:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:0;
top:0;
left:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
background:#000;
transition:all 1s ease;
-ms-transition:all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
}
header {
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
float:left;
width:100%;
background:#F00;
border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
height:60px;
}
nav {
position:fixed;
margin-left:-200px;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:0;
width:200px;
height:100%;
float:left;
color:#fff;
background:#030e17;
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
}
nav a {
display:block;
}
#content {
width:100%;
height:30000px;
}
#menuToggle {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#0cff00;
cursor:pointer;
}
.push {
left:200px;
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may bee able to do it with CSS, just putting an overflow:hidden on the body...

You could also use this JS below to disable the touchmove event:

JS:

```
$(window).bind(
   'touchmove',
   function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks this JS worked but i now cannot scroll the .wrapper. Is there anyway i could use this but ensure that the user can scroll vertically on touch?